# Power Query from files in Folder specify column selection

Tags: import, powerquery

I think I need to specify the columns to be imported from files in a folder, as the auto-generated files that are scheduled to save to the location have a title in cell A1 with header/data table further Starting at row 6.
As there is only one column with data in row 1, Power Query only pulls in column A to work with.  But I need it to pull in Columns A to E so that I can perform the Transform to get the table data I need.

Can I specify the columns for Power Query to recognize so I can get all my data?

Example data:[image]

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you in powerquery

Assuming they are all .xlsx files in the same directory you can edit below, should merge in the data into a nice table

```
let Source = Folder.Files("C:\directory\subdirectory\"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".xlsx")),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Name", "Content"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "GetFileData", each Excel.Workbook([Content],true)),
#"Expanded GetFileData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "GetFileData", {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Name"}, {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Sheet"}),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded GetFileData", "TimePeriod", each Table.FirstN(Table.DemoteHeaders([Data]),5){2}[Column2]),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2", "Summary", each Table.FirstN(Table.DemoteHeaders([Data]),5){3}[Column2]),
#"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Data2", each Table.Skip([Data],5)),
List = List.Union(List.Transform(#"Added Custom3"[Data], each Table.ColumnNames(_))),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom3","Data2", List,List),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Data",{"Content", "Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Sheet"}),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Trip Odometer", "Vehicle"}, {"Column2", "Duration"}, {"Column3", "GPS Distance"}, {"Column4", "CAN Distance"}})
in  #"Renamed Columns"
```

Comment: did this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of the data you're working with, but were it me, I'd first consider simply opening the powerquery advanced editor with things not working just as you described above, open that in the line(s) after the source is specified tell it to skip the rows add:
`skip = List.Skip(src,6),`
Close Save and Load.  See wha'happens